# Is it possible to use GPVAL_Y_MIN and GPVAL_Y_MAX in multiplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting six differents graphs in a multiplot. I would like to autoscale axis. Values that are plotted are readed from txt files that are different in each execution, so I can't fix any value in xrange and yrange. That's why I need to autoscaling axis.

The problem is that multiplot doesn't allow to change term, so I can't plot in a dummy terminal and I don't know GPVAL_Y_MIN and GPVAL_Y_MAX values.

Any ideas? If graphs in multiplot don't have correct scale it is not very useful to display my data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
set autoscale yfix
```

to have an autoscaled y-range but without extending it to the next tics. This would give you different ranges for each subplot.

If you need one yrange for all subplots, you can use the `stats` command (requires version 4.6). Using `GPVAL_Y_*` after plotting to a dummy terminal was the way to go for gnuplot versions prior to 4.6 (more a workaround).

Then you can iterate over all files to determine the common yrange:

```
filelist="A.txt B.txt C.txt D.txt E.txt F.txt"
i = 0
do for [f in filelist] {
    stats f using 1:2 nooutput
    if (i == 0) { 
        min_y = STATS_min_y
        max_y = STATS_max_y
        i = 1
    } else {
        min_y = (STATS_min_y < min_y ? STATS_min_y : min_y)
        max_y = (STATS_max_y > max_y ? STATS_max_y : max_y)
    }
}
set yrange [min_y:max_y]
set multiplot 
...
```

Comment: First of all, thanks. It's a good idea, I suppose, but what happens if two graphs have very large differences on y values? For example 0,015 and 3500 in the other. It could be a problem if one of the plots works with small values and other plot uses much bigger values. I don't know if you understand what I mean, do you?

Comment: (depending on plot, values are mmm, Hz, J, N, kg...)

Comment: I didn't understand, what you exactly meant in your question and so I posted the two only situations which I can image make sense with `GPVAL_*`. Of course it doesn't make sense to have a common yrange if you plot different quantities! So: what do you want to achieve exactly? Why doesn't the autoscaling and possible use of `set autoscale yfix` work?

Comment: Ok autoscale improves plots, thanks. I set the size of all plots manually, and one of them is smaller than others. I though it could be solved using autoscale (x and y) but no. Thanks, you have solved my problem, but now I have other haha.

Comment: This is the part of my multiplot which is failing: (http://box.jisko.net/i/46811d74.png)  I can't use multiplot layout because I need to add two logos up beside the tittle. So I set plots position and size individually, but I don't understand why these seems wrong. It could be because of the values?

Comment: Seems like you are using `set size ratio -1`, which gives you the wrong sizes, because it uses the same scales for both axes. Consider the simple example `reset; set size ratio -1; plot 20*x`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! The problem was that before plotting logos I wrote: "set size ratio -1; unset key; unset tics; unset border"  and then I didn't reset it correctly